# same model with diferent prediction betwen python and javascript tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

Hello I am exporting arcface model from python to tensorflow.js in python I got the following prediction:

```
-2.47331879e+02,  2.43775589e+02,  1.48011673e+02,....
```

But in javascript, I got the following.

```
-247.3305206298828,243.7752685546875,148.0111541748047,....
```

But the input is the same image, the only different thing is that in TensorFlow, I needed to cast the array to tensor using the following line:

```
  face = tf.tensor(face[0][0])
```

Why I am getting different results?

**EDIT**

I am using this code in order to get the image as array in python and in javascript

Python code:

```
img = Image.open('file.jpg')
img = img.resize((112, 112), Image.ANTIALIAS)
img = np.expand_dims(img, axis=0)
img = tf.convert_to_tensor(img, dtype='int32')
```

Image is save in a file with the following code:

```
with open('data.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(np.array(img).tolist(), outfile)
```

And paste in a variable in javascript code.

Javascript code:

```
 face = tf.tensor(face[0][0], [1, 112, 112, 3], 'int32')
 const display = document.getElementById('display');
 modelLayer.then(model => display.innerHTML = 
 model.predict(face).dataSync())
```

**EDIT2**

The euclidean distance between javascript prediction and Python prediction is 0.021145982611487882

Thanks

Comment: These numbers seem pretty close to each other, so I'm guessing it has something to do with the precision of the numbers used in Python vs JavaScript.

Comment: I think the same, but I would like if is possible truncate to the same "precission" in both languagues

Answer (score 0):

Like Most likely a number precision thing

Which backend are you using in TFJS? WASM had terrible precision, but it has improved in TFJS 3.11 although it's still lower precision than WebGL.

What is number types is saved model using (dump `model.summary()` to check)?
If model itself is using something like `float64` (not uncommon), of course precision in TFJS will be lower as there is no 64bit support in TFJS (WebGL itself doesn't have 64bit precision, so TFJS cannot even attempt it)

And even with WebGL, `float32` is more like `float30` due to precision loss in GL itself when its working with shaders.